# How to store at byte addresses in MIPS assembly?

Tags: assembly, mips

My homework says:

1. Ask the user for an integer P; store this in symbolic address p
2. Ask the user for a 21-character string S with the 21st character always being null
3. Interpret P as a byte address and store S starting at P(even if S has less than 21 characters, store the characters sequentially still starting at byte address P)

what I don't understand is, we are using .data which starts with 0x10010000 and we have to use the integer P as a byte address so the possible addresses for P is 0x00000000 + integer.

How can I access addresses 0x00000000 + integer ?
It would produce an error address out of range: 0x00000001 (for example)

Comment: Just use `($t0)` or whichever register your integer is in. Note it's the job of your user to input valid address then.

Comment: what valid input address can be used then?

Comment: You said yourself, that `.data` starts at `0x10010000` so something higher than that presumably. Depends on your environment.

Comment: ohh I see. As I thought so, the mistake is that I use 4296015872 instead of 268500992 :)) thank you!